# what happening with this CSS3? i can't find it

Tags: html, css

i have made a button with some effects. When i tested in browser it's working fine in only in mozilla. i am unable to find why is not working in -webkit- browser can anybody tell me why this code is not working check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/Qtw3x/

**here is html code**

```
<button name="feat-btn" id="feat-btn" class="push-button" type="submit">
    <span>Submit</span>
</button>
```

**here is css**

```
.push-button {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: medium none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.push-button span:after {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: #357536 transparent -moz-use-text-color;
    border-image: none;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-style: solid solid none;
    border-width: 5px 5px 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin: 0 -1.7em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
.push-button span:before {
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.push-button span {
    background-color: #4FB051;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6FBE70;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 49px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    min-width: 110px;
    padding: 0 1.7em;
    position: relative;
}
.push-button:hover  span{background-color:#52a853;}
```

first check it in `mozilla` then you understand how it will look or you can see the image below 
this is looking in `mozilla` 
[image]

and this is looking in webkit browser
[image]

Comment: Why do you have a `span` tag inside the button? Why not just have the plain text inside the opening and closing `button` tags?

Comment: @zuallauz for put effect like 3d

Comment: More importantly why are you using non-standard border color properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something weird is going on with your `border-color` in the `.push-button span:after` selector

```
border-color: #357536 transparent -moz-use-text-color;
```

Just change it to `#357537`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/8Me8m/)

```
border-color: #357536;
```

Works in both Chrome and Firefox for me with that change.

Comment: Adding to Daniel's answer: `-moz-use-text-color` seems to be causing your style to break. You shouldn't be using that anyway since it has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions#border-color). Use `currentColor` instead, it doesn't break on Chrome.

Comment: @Vimal Stan: Not like it ever was intended for use in Web stylesheets in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

delete

```
   transparent -moz-use-text-color
```

from the line

```
   border-color: #357536 transparent -moz-use-text-color;
```

I dont see any changes, but works fine.
Result is:

```
  border-color: #357536;
```